# Resources tag is difficult to find for new users

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'm saying this from experience. When I posted [my question about OP and ED ratings](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8567/where-can-i-find-ratings-of-anime-ops-and-eds), I couldn't find an appropriate tag by searching **"rating"**, **"site"** and **"list"**. I didn't even think to look for [resources](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).

Here's the tag's current excerpt:

> For questions to help users find useful and valid resources that other community members may use on a variety of subjects related to the topic of the site.

Even though it has the word "site" in it, it doesn't show up when you write "site" into tag section.

I propose to add tag synonyms [anime-site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-site), [rating-site](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rating-site), and maybe [anime-list](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-list) so that [resources](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) would at least show up in tag section.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I was asking a question about where to watch animes whithout subs legally and didn't know what tag to add. Not once when asking questions like these do you think of "resources".

Comment: Although I am not a technically a new user [82 days so far and counting] and I had difficulty finding it.

Comment: @MiharuDante your question and Krazer's edit inspired me to post this proposition. When I asked my question, I was a 1 year user and I had this problem.

Comment: @user1306322 To be fair, this isn't a particularly serious issue, simply because we don't get many questions that merit the [tag:resources] tag. High-rep users that are aware of the tag can just edit it in when appropriate.

Comment: The problem is that there's no one-size fits all solution for this. The proposed tags synonym are a bit arbitrary and are only helpful in fringe cases. Instead, I think we need to better educate users about what non-series tags are available and how to use them.

Comment: @Krazer I think it's easier to retag manually for now, and even when question rate rises, but I don't think teaching users (btw, how?) is going to be easier than adding a number of obvious tag synonyms.